# Pass json string in url

Tags: json

I have a url like

> events.ktass.com/graze/v1/addSituationCustomInfo?auth_token='+cc+'&sitn_id='+bb+'&**custom_info={incrf":'+aa+'}**
>   I want to apend json string like this  **custom_info={'incrf':'aa'}**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sending this from your browser's address bar or CURL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (note the double not single quotes):

```
{"incrf":"aa"}
```

To ensure that no characters that have special meaning in a URL are included, put the JSON String through [EncodingUtil.urlEncode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlEncode) when you add it to the URL and through [EncodingUtil.urlDecode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlDecode) when you take it out of the URL.

The above JSON encodes to:

```
%7B%22incrf%22%3A%22aa%22%7D
```

This approach is best used with quite short JSON (a few hundred characters) as maximum URL length limits across the internet are somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: Actually, the *browsers* are no longer the problem-- salesforce.com appears to have a limit of about 7500 characters for a URL, which is far less than any modern browser supports in a URL. Limits to other platforms will most likely be server-based, not client-based, as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've Googled before to try to get a definitive view with things like proxy servers used by businesses also potentially imposing limits. A cautious maximum to stay under from that Googling was 2k. But good to know Salesforce's limit.